# how can i create multiple git repository project in teamcity

Tags: github, teamcity

I have 10 different projects, each one has its own git repository.
All these projects should be built the same way.

I am looking for a way to create one Build project in teamcity and make this project listen to the 10 repos. (I don't want to create 10 teamcity projects, each one listen to a repository). Teamcity should be triggered when there is a change in any project (i.e. git commit), Teamcity should build just the project that got changed (not all projects). Let's assume that the build project has one command to run "yarn build".

As I understood from this answer
https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206155229-Multiple-VCS-Roots-for-Same-Build-Configuration

There is no way to do that, however the answer was in 2015.

My questions are:

1- Could you please confirm if there is any way to achieve this requirement in teamcity.

2- If not, what is the best practice to handle such scenario.

Comment: it's possible. how you should build? some command? how? build all or some project? please add this information to the question body and left the comment for me.

Comment: Thanks @SeniorPomidor, i updated the question, only the project that got changed should be built, lets assume that i wanna run just one command "yarn build"

Comment: you cannot detect automatically which specific vcs was changed for running yarn build only for these changes. but it's able to run yarn build for a specific project depends on variable of build.